# Reference for easy understanding of calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Can you please suggest some books or websites for higher secondary school student for easy understanding of calculus?(Just I want to learn to carry out basic calculations)

Comment: A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis, John Bell.

Comment: @mistermarko : That book looks like an attempt to be logically rigorous with nilpotent infinitesimals.  Nilpotent infinitesimals might be useful in a book for secondary students, but I suspect showing the reader how to make them logically rigorous is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think you meant to address the OP :)

Comment: I'd say it depends a lot on the nature of the student's interests. If you're intersted in pure mathematics and have the prerequisites down solidly, then more-or-less conventional texts may be suitable. If you're interested in understanding why calculus is important, from the non-mathematician's point of view, maybe _Calculus in Context_ would be good. There's also Sylvanus Thompson's _Calculus Made Easy_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Do you just want to learn how to carry out basic calculations, or do you want to understand the material in depth?

Comment: Thank you for your answers friends....

Comment: I once wrote a [post](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1259) for my students that's supposed to give an understanding of calculus. Interestingly, it's about the *understanding* and not about the mechanics, so this may or may not facilitate basic calculations

Comment: Possibly the most basic treatment I know of is Ferrar's **Calculus for Beginners**. While I was still taking a first course in school algebra (in fact, this was during the first 2 or 3 months of the algebra course) I saw a copy of Ferrar's book at a public library, checked it out, and was able to read the first 20 or 30 pages (past the limit definition of a derivative) with a fair amount of understanding. (This was in Fall 1973, if anyone is interested.)